# How to return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

See my code and please see what is my problem

```
$('#StartPiCam').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "StartPiCam",
                type: "GET",
                data: "value=1",
                //dataType: "json",
                //success: onDataReceived
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "PiCam_Brightness",
                type: "GET",
                data: "Brightness={$('#Brightness').val()}",
                //dataType: "json",
                //success: onDataReceived
            });
        });
```

```
<INPUT ID="Brightness" TYPE=TEXT NAME="Brightness" VALUE="50" SIZE=12 MAXLENGTH=3 NOFINSIDE="~!   ~!" >
```

it returns 0 but I expect returning the value of the input "Brightness"

Comment: Are you trying to send the value of the input to your server?

Comment: what do you mean 'returns zero' , do you mean your server side code is acting as though it receives a zero from the ajax call? What data type is the server expecting to receive?

Comment: There's no `return` statement anywhere in your code, so what exactly is returning 0? Maybe all you need is data: `Brightness=${$('#Brightness').val()}`? (i.e., use tick marks instead of double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the data format

This would work according to me.

```
$('#StartPiCam').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "StartPiCam",
                type: "GET",
                data: {value: '1'},
                //dataType: "json",
                //success: onDataReceived
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "PiCam_Brightness",
                type: "GET",
                data: {Brightness: $('#Brightness').val()}",
                //dataType: "json",
                //success: onDataReceived
            });
        });
```

Comment: Good to know. Keep Coding!